# Querying related Period from ForecastingQuota

Tags: soql

I'm trying to query relationships to the Period object, specifically ForecastingQuota (in either direction) and have found that the query does not work because the relationship is not found.

The query that fails is:

```
Select Id, Period.Id from ForecastingQuota
```

A similar query from ForecastingItem is successful:

```
Select Id, Period.Id from ForecastingItem
```

Is there a general issue with this relationship between ForecastingQuota and Period, or am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Could you figure out why you can not query the relationship fields of the Period object from forecastingQuote?